# Delphi TPngImageList save/load from file

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-7

I'd like to load and save TPngImageList (Delphi7 version, PngComponents) from/to file (better single PNG file for all 20 png icons in image list). I can't find `LoadFromFile/SaveToFile` methods.

How to do it?

Comment: I've never heard of a `TPngImageList`. Did you get it from here: https://code.google.com/p/cubicexplorer/downloads/list ?

Comment: @Jerry seems yes, I got it from here, same folders/files.

Comment: Up to date link: https://github.com/TurboPack/PNGComponents

Answer (score 2):

`TPngImageList` derives from `TImageList`, which does not support that for bitmaps/icons, and `TPngImageList` does not add support for it for pngs.

You will have to load the file into a `TPNGImage` first, then manually split it (which is not easy, if transparency/alpha is involved) into pieces that you can `Add()` into the `TPngImageList`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to split it. I think the underlying image list control can accept all the images supplied as a singe tiled image. See ImageList_LoadImage.

Comment: That only works for bitmaps, though.  Remember, this is a png imagelist instead.

Comment: Is ready function to load from file exists, and save to? Maybe which uses DFM format.Or PNG.Or BMP

Comment: @RProgram This is what Remy said, no it does not support such a thing. You will need to do this yourself.

Comment: 30 icons. Do u think loading 30 PNGs is fast? Or ZIP with no compression, with PNGs, fast?

Comment: @Remy So convert to a bitmap and call `ImageList_LoadImage`. Pretty much a two liner. Obviously care needs to be taken with transparency. Personally I'd load a single PNG, convert to bitmap, and use `TImageList`.

Comment: Why convert to bitmap and lose the advantages that PNG offer?

Comment: @Remy No advantages are lost at all. The underlying control stores it as a bitmap so at some point it is going to be a bitmap. I don't mean throw away PNG compression. I juist mean to do an in memory conversion to a bitmap (HBITMAP) and put that straight into the image list. What do you think the control will do when it is given a PNG image and asked to add it to the HIMAGELIST?